# ubuntu:display number of files using pattern

Tags: ubuntu

this is my code that should display number of files whose start with a and contain k and end with (.txt) under the home directory.

```
ls | sed -n "/a*k*.txt/p"
```

but there is an error i did not know where.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use sed. wc is the right command here for counting:

```
ls a*k*.txt | wc -l
```

With sed would be like this:

```
ls | sed -n "/^a.*k.*\.txt$/p"
```

Answer (score 1):

This one never fails:

```
ls -1 ~/a*k*.txt | wc -l
```

Event when there is an error like the following:

```
/usr/bin/ls: cannot access /home/ichramm/a*k*.txt: No such file or directory
```

The error is printed to `stderr` so it is not caught by `wc`, which means it will always give the expected value.